# Adding or appending object with object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, ember.js

i am having 2 objects and the code is

Object 1

```
var existingValue=self.get('objHubDto').ftd.gridDataDTO.gridDTOMap[name].gridDataMap;
```

Object 2

```
var newValue =  self.get('childDataList')
```

I need to merge/add/append this two in newvalue value eventhough it having duplicate key values

Comment: An Object cannot have duplicate keys, it always will use the value for second one passed when merging.

Comment: yes i know.. but is there any way to alllow the duplicate values

Comment: keep the values in an array when keys are same, `duplicate values are never a problem but keys are`.

Comment: can you just show the examples how to keep the values in array when keys are same

Comment: added in answers.

Comment: okay will try ..Thanks fro your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a very basic example to merge by keeping both values, however, you can create new object rather mutating existing one.

```js
let obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let obj2 = { a: 9, d: 8, e: 7 };

Object.entries(obj2).forEach(([key, val]) => {
 obj1[key] = obj1[key] ? [obj1[key], val] : val;
});

console.log(obj1);
```